# Google Sheets -> Excel Power Query Import Failing

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a workbook that's been working perfectly for months. It fetches data from a google sheet using Power Query, imports it into Excel where some manipulation takes place. This week it has started simply importing the raw XML from Google sheets and it broke my whole spreadsheet.

The Google Sheets Data is published to this URL:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSKZgwPTi5cHOQEIREZSt6DT5j10jV8YGM_qNpQKibA_3bqG0WTmhgBf5qpEGQtVZbZtyG0qjz17QuK/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv

When I import it into Excel is simply shows as this:
[image: Excel Power Query]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this solution in Google forum, worked for me:
*"I went to share and changed the permissions to anyone with the link can edit and now my publish to web excel file is working again"*, posted by User 9796698160247565283

Here's the thread: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/83654137?hl=en

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much!